# Windows 10 Media Creation Tool unable to boot in UEFI mode

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, bios, uefi

I've downloaded the last Windows 10 Media Creation Tool (https://www.microsoft.com/it-it/software-download/windows10) in order to install Windows 10 in UEFI mode (**before it was Legacy**)

The USB stick looks good, it is **FAT32** and it has the correct EFI boot files: **efi/boot/bootx64.efi** as well as **efi/boot/windows/BCD** etc..

So it looks like a UEFI bootable USB.

However, I can enter the Windows setup only in **Legacy** mode with the **CSM enabled**.
MY mobo is an **AsRock AB350 pro4** and I've already installed the last good firmware for my Ryzen5 1600x.
If I install windows 10 in this way, the result will be a **Legacy** installation.

If I try to disable the **CSM**, I can choose to boot from the **UEFI:<USB stick name>**, however it displays the AsRock logo and keep restarting.

I've also tried to burn the iso with **Rufus** yet I got the same result...

In all of my thousands of tries, I've also checked another UEFI boot image (Gandalf's Windows 10PE x64 Redstone 5) and with that I was able to boot in UEFI.

In BIOS I've tried to disable Secure Boot and fTPM without success...

Why does my system does not sees Windows 10 bootable in UEFI mode?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a Setup.exe file on the USB.  If so run Setup and see if it starts. You would need the option to Keep Nothing.

Comment: Your image is not correctly built to run in UEFI mode. You should use Rufus, take iso that supports UEFI, record a USB stick with Rufus using GPT and NTFS mode (to support image file bigger than 4 GB)

Comment: https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-turbo/1565621/rthc07bd146dc92659b4b60792b2dddb618/max_g360_c12_r3x4_pd20

Comment: Secure Boot and fTPM has nothing to do with your inability to boot to the disk in question.  Those features should remained enabled. If your current system was installed with Legacy mode enabled, and you have not converted your installation using MBR2GPT, you should do that before you reinstall Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your suggestions, yet they were not usefull.
Finally, the way I solved my problem, was to **update the BIOS of my AsRock AB350 pro4** to version **P5.00**. Previously it was **P4.60**.

After the update, it was able to correctly detect the UEFI Windows 10 USB.